# Rails - Using custom bootstrap Modal for confirmation

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I want to use Botostrap Modal for delete confirmation.

However my Modal is not getting invoked when I click the link "Click here"

```
<table id='employee-table' class="table table-hover">
    <thead  class="thead-light">
      <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th colspan="2"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @projects.each_with_index do |project, index| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= index + 1 %></td>
          <td><%= project.id %></td>
          <td><%= project.title %></td>
          <td><%= link_to "Manage Users", add_users_path(project), :class => "btn btn-outline-success", :style => "float:right"%></td>
          <td><%= link_to "Delete Project", project_path(project), :class => "btn btn-outline-danger", :style => "float:right", method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Deleting a project will also remove all its associated employee records, any bugs and/ or feature requests. Are you sure?' } %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Click Here', "#", data: {toggle: "modal", target: "#exampleModal"} %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>


  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I double checked the id, it is pointing to the modal name (with a # at the start).

All of this is defined in the file show.html.erb

Can someone point out the problem in this?

Comment: Shouldn't 'Click Here' be a button instead of a link?

Comment: Does it matter? I'll just wrap it with 'btn' class and it will be presented as a button.